# Have problem with JavaScript .filter and .find to return items with specific letters

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following JavaScript code, I am trying to get names that have the letter "Y" or "y". When I looked up how to do that, I saw `.filter` and `.find` methods. But this code only returns `containsY = ['Tommy']`. I tried `for loop`, but `.find` only returns the value of the first element in the provided condition, and it doesn't return all names with "y"s. Is there any better way to get all of "Y" and "y" names?

```
const students = ["Tommy","Noah","Xander","Adil","Bradley","Nicholas","Damien"]

let containsY = students.filter((student) => student.includes("Y"))

//Look for name with "y", and push it to containsY
containsY.push(students.find((student) => student.includes("y")))

console.log(containsY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a regular expression (which has the benefit of only requiring a single test)

```js
const students = ["Tommy", "Noah", "Xander", "Adil", "Bradley", "Nicholas", "Damien"]
const result = students.filter(student => /y/i.test(student))
console.log(result)
```

Or test for both `.includes('y')` and `.includes('Y')` in (a single) callback.

```js
const students = ["Tommy", "Noah", "Xander", "Adil", "Bradley", "Nicholas", "Damien"]
const result = students.filter(student => student.includes('y') || student.includes('Y'));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Testing with single callback looks much more concise! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `filter` approach is fine. It's giving incorrect results because
[`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is case sensitive.

Instead, inside the `filter` callback, convert `student` to lowercase, then check whether it includes `"y"`:

```js
const students = ["Tommy","Noah","Xander","Adil","Bradley","Nicholas","Damien"]

const res = students.filter((student) => student.toLowerCase().includes("y"))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't know that .includes is case sensitive :)